# Laravel / Eloquent - When date is in the past

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am working on an application which uses Laravel and Eloquent that determines whether something (a job) has not been completed on time. This is stored as a `DATE` within the table. E.g. `2016-07-18`

I am trying to get all the records where todays date is greater than the "completed_date" stored inside the table.

Here is what I have tried:

```
$id = \Auth::user()->id;
$now = \Carbon\Carbon::today();

$jobs = Job::whereHas('manager', function ($user) use ($id) {
   $user->where('users.id', '=', $id);
})->where('complete_date', '>', $now)->get();
```

The issue is that it's still retrieving records that are in the future. For example, the record it returns, I checked the table and the "complete_date" is `2016-08-31`

Any ideas please?

Comment: You should do `->where('complete_date', '<', $now)->get();` !! not `>`

Comment: @Maraboc Doing not brings back a lot more rows. I want to check if the `complete_date` is above today, therefore, it's overdue

Comment: I didn't inderstand your needs exactly :p

Comment: Try using the `whereDate` instead of `where`.

Comment: @Maraboc Basically. If I assign you a job that needs to be completed on the 26th of July (Yesterday) and you didn't complete it and logged in today (28th) the system would detect that you have overdue tasks

Comment: In that case i think you must add a field to the job table to indicate that the job is done,  then your query may look like this `->where('complete_date', '<', $now)->where('jobDone', false)->get();`

Answer (score -4):

Your *$now* variable is a Carbon object, not a date.

You have to convert the object to a date:

```
$now = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');
```

Then you have to use this variable in your model query.

Comment: Carbon gets converted to dates automatically when used in queries. No need to manually format it.

Comment: @ceejayoz, Carbon automatically gets converted into 'Y-m-d H:i:s' not 'Y-m-d'. Since database type `DATE` hasn't time part, default Carbon format can be considered as not valid for comparison, can't it?

Comment: @Phargelm I've had no issues passing a Carbon date right to a `DATE` field. Laravel appears to handle it internally just fine (or the SQL server automatically handles it, perhaps).